# Двойное условие на сигнал в connect

Tags: c++, qt, сигналы-слоты

Можно ли сделать двойное условие на сигнал (например, при нажатии на кнопку  в одном случае срабатывала одна функция, а при другом - другая)
Что-то вроде

`connect(ui->button, SIGNAL(clicked() && k = 0), this, SLOT(func1()))`

Comment: Да, вам надо делать как в ответе ниже, потому что SIGNAL и SLOT это макросы результат которых есть `const char *`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно, чтобы оставлять код чистым, если нужно сделать подобное, я применяю привязку к слоту лямбда выражения....

```
QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, [=]() {
    if(k==0) {
        emit signalOne();
    } else {
        emit signalTwo();
    }
} );
```

Эту возможность добавили недавно, в учебных материалах может не фигурировать. В официальной документации место под её описание выделили [тут](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax/ru).

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял, вместо signalOne() и two я должен подставить свои функции? В таком случае, у меня, почему-то не работает )

Comment: Лямбда выражение - обычная функция. Да, ей можно передать указатель this и вызвать метод класса. Если речь идет о вызове функции, то ключевое слово emit следует убрать - оно для сигнала

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!